# How do I switch between the most recently-used instances of a single app in Gnome 3?

Tags: gnome

Numerous other questions touch on how to cycle between applications in Gnome 3, but I haven't seen one yet that answers the above question.

Specifically, **I want to switch between the two most recently used terminal windows**.

For reference, I know that:

- `` Alt + ` `` cycles instances of the same application, but not necessarily the most recently used ones.
- `Alt + Tab` cycles the most recently applications, but won't work for different instances of the same application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ctrl+shift+tab` should switch between instances of the same application.

Here is the full [list of shortcuts](https://wiki.gnome.org/Design/OS/KeyboardShortcuts).